# What is the difference in meaning between "se laisser + infinitif" and "se faire + infinitif"?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, constructions-causatives

> Tant mieux. Comme ça, tu **te laisseras moins mener** par le bout du nez.
>
> Tant mieux. Comme ça, tu **te feras moins mener** par le bout du nez.

I’m not sure when to use "se laisser + infinitif" and when to use "se faire + infinitif".

Comment: One can "se laisser mourir" but can not "se faire mourir". It's all about passive/active form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans les deux cas, le sujet subit l'action.
Cependant, comme l'expliquent Steeven Brunner et Nico Mezeret,
Une différence notable démarque **"se faire + inf"** et **"se laisser + inf"**

---

### Se faire + inf :

Le sujet subit l'action sans avoir les moyens de faire autrement.

> Se faire harceler.

### Se laisser + inf :

Le sujet a les moyens de ne pas subir, mais comme le dit bien Nico Mezeret, il reste néanmoins passif.

> Se laisser vivre.
>   Se laisser aller.

---

### Translated

In both cases, the subject undergoes the action. But, a point between **"se faire + inf"** and **"se laisser + inf"** is significantly different :

---

### Se faire + inf :

The subject has no way not to undergo the action.

> Se faire harceler.

### Se laisser + inf :

The subject can prevent the action, but keeps passive and undergoes.

> Se laisser vivre.
>   Se laisser aller.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not really easy to explain it in english so let me know if you don't understand.

La différence ici se trouve au niveau de la 'responsabilité' de la personne.

Dans le cas suivant:

> Tu te feras moins mener par le bout du nez.

On considère que cela est arrivé une fois à la personne de façon involontaire et que ça lui servira de leçon.

Dans l'autre cas :

> Tu te laisseras moins mener par le bout du nez.

On considère ici que la personne s'est 'laissée faire', qu'elle aurait pû éviter ce qui lui est arrivé en quelque sorte.

The difference is not that huge.

Comment: Ce qu'il faut comprendre, c'est que contrairement à "se faire + inf", "se laisser + inf" signifie que le sujet subit alors qu'il a les moyens de ne pas subir.

Comment: @Charly pourrais-tu transformer ce commentaire clair et précis en réponse ?

Comment: Je l'écris, mais ça fait un peu doublon avec d'autres réponses déjà fournies.

Comment: En fait, je penses qu'une réponse très courte telle que celle que tu as faite en commentaire était idéale et que les réponses actuelles sont inutilement bavardes.

Comment: L'auteur de la question et d'autres personnes y ont trouvés leur compte, là est l'essentiel. Mieux vaut une réponse plus détaillée que l'inverse. Et on est pas dans l'abus ici, en 10 lignes il n'y a pas de remplissage ;)

Answer (score 2):

In a broader sense, « *se laisser faire* » is a verb used when a person is passive about something that is happening to them.

> Je me laisse faire porter = I am letting someone carry me.

*Se faire + verb*, however, is used when something is happening to a person without them having a say in it

> Je me fais porter = someone is carrying me

With regards to your example,

> Tant mieux. Comme ça, tu te laisseras moins mener par le bout du nez.

indicates some level of awareness by the person, and will not let themselves be played anymore.

> Tant mieux. Comme ça, tu te feras moins mener par le bout du nez.

on the other hand, indicates that the person now has a way of identifying when they are being played and stop it happening.